# How can I translate an Excel table into a Relational Database Table Design?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have a table of data and I want to make sure that I am correctly formatting it for database table design.

The following Excel table/chart shows different outcomes for different combinations of goals and sizes:

```
        fast  ave  slow
small    A     B     C
med      D     E     F
large    G     H     I
```

After converting from an Excel format and normalization, I ended up with the following 3 tables for the database:

Table for goals:

```
**goal**
id  name
1   fast
2   ave
3   slow
```

Table for Size:

```
**size**
id  name
1   small
2   med
3   large
```

Table for Outcomes which stores the outcomes of the different size and goal combinations:

```
**outcome**
id  goal_id   size_id   name
1      1         1        A
2      2         1        B
3      3         1        C
4      1         2        D
5      2         2        E
6      3         2        F
7      1         3        G
8      2         3        H
9      3         3        I
```

There would be the following one-to-many relationships:
1) goal to outcome
2) size to outcome

Am I on the right track or am I missing a key concept?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have this application relationship & table:

```
-- outcome of goal GOAL with size SIZE has name NAME
Outcome(goal, size, name)

goal      size     name
fast      small    A
ave       small    B
slow      small    C
fast      med      D
ave       med      E
slow      med      F
fast      large    G
ave       large    H
slow      large    I
```

Normalization does not involve introducing new column names or values. You might want to use ids instead of values (why?) and ids for relationship instances (why?), but it's not normalization. Normalization is about replacing a table by other tables that always join to it.

The CK for my Outcome is (goal, size). There are reasons for & against introducing ids in various situations. But here since the whole point of the table is to look up via goal & size it's hard to see why you would need an id. (Some ORMs unfortunately require you to have a one-column CK.)

Your "relationships" are relational database FKs (foreign keys). A FK is from a table & column list to a table & column list. (Such "relationships" are actually facts about pairs of tables. Application relationships are represented by tables.) Declare one when whenever the values for a list of columns in one source/referencing table must appear as values for a list of columns in a target/referenced table and the latter columns form a CK (candidate key) in the latter table. A CK is a set of columns that are unique in a table but that doesn't contain a smaller such set. Given your tables with `_id`s, you need:

```
FOREIGN KEY outcome (goal_id) REFERENCES goal (goal_id)
FOREIGN KEY outcome (size_id) REFERENCES size (size_id)
```

PS Re surrogate vs natural PK/CK: Research this. (Beware--lots of nonsense out there.) A surrogate CK is needed when users of a system need a new name for something but the db doesn't store any natural CK. (Some people don't even call such ids surrogates.) Called for when natural CKs might change. Used just to be shorter than any multicolumn natural CKs. Frequently used because DBMSs don't hide implementation: Eg they can be faster & smaller for indexing etc. PS The notion of PK is not very helpful. Beware of presentations in terms of PKs rather than CKs. Always have a reason before you complicate a design.

Comment: Based on your answer, it sounds like I am just creating extra tables when, in fact, I should just use one table such as this:

**outcome**
[id    goal           size     name]
[1      fast         small        A]
[2      ave         small        B]
[3      slow        small        C]
[4      fast         med        D]
[5      ave         med        E]
[6      slow        med        F]
[7      fast         large        G]
[8      ave         large        H]
[9      slow        large        I]

Is this correct?

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that a surrogate key (instead of a composite key) should be used for a primary key.  Obviously, I am new to database design, so I am unclear as to why one would use the surrogate versus the composite (other than it seems it would be simpler to type).